# Consumption usage returns incorrect result using $filter

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am querying Usage details list of Consumption service using additional filters. These are my params:

```
properties/consumedService eq 'Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL' and properties/usageStart ge '2019-08-07T00:00:00Z' and properties/usageEnd lt '2019-08-09T01:00:00Z'
```

Here is my full URL:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2019-01-01&%24filter=properties%2FconsumedService%20eq%20%27Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL%27%20and%20properties%2FusageStart%20ge%20%272019-08-07T00%3A00%3A00Z%27%20and%20properties%2FusageEnd%20lt%20%272019-08-09T01%3A00%3A00Z%27
```

It returns success 200 OK response. BUT filter by date works fine, filter by consumed service returns a lot of unwanted information like `"consumedService": "Microsoft.Sql", "consumedService": "Microsoft.Storage", and even "consumedService": "Microsoft.Compute"`. Why is that happening? I need for example full usage of PotgreSQL or MySQL databases. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with $filter=Properties/ConsumedService eq 'Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL'

Comment: It returns same result